# How to know end status of execution of command in batch programming

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to cache clear in Mozilla browser by following command

```
@echo off
set DataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
rd /s /q "%DataDir%"
for /d %%x in (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*) do del /q /s /f %%x\*sqlite
```

It is working fine but how can i make sure that execution of the command is completed i.e. cache in mozilla browser is cleared.

Comment: `CMD.EXE` puts the exit code of a command in the `%ERRORLEVEL%` environment variable. Generally, and by convention, a value of `0` signals success and other values indicate a `failure`.

Comment: Thanks for response , but how can i use it , can u give me example.

Comment: You typically have this after *each* command: `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO failure`, and then add a failure label and commands to be executed in the event of failure.

Comment: K, Thanks a lot , one more query , our Windows Operating System can be in any directory i. e. instead of in C: , it can be in D: or in any another directory . Is any way is available to find out current location(directory) of System Windows Operating System in script.

Comment: You should ask a separate question. But nevertheless, try the `%SystemDrive%` environment variable.

Comment: But if your asking because of the drive on which `Users` is located, you might be better of, just using `%APPDATAT%` instead of `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%` respectively (also see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) or just type `set` in your console window).

Comment: Thanks once more , but %SystemDriver% or %APPDATA% is not working. I used as %SystemDriver%:\Users\%USERNAME%\%APPDATA%\Roaming in stead of C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming , and %SystemDriver%:\Users\%USERNAME%\%APPDATA%\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles instead of C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles . Is any error in my use ?

Comment: K Thanks a lot now it works fine because i was using as %SystemDrive%: instead of %SystemDrive% .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as Christian.K stated, you can use %ERRORLEVEL% to determine the success or failure of each command executed.  Lasse V. Karlsen stated, you can fail on this %ERRORLEVEL%'s value.  Example using your code below:

```
@echo off
set DataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto :failure

rd /s /q "%DataDir%"
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto :failure

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%x in (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*) do (
    del /q /s /f %%x\*sqlite
    if !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto :failure
)
endlocal
goto :EOF

:failure
echo do something here
exit
goto :EOF
```

1. Use NEQ 0 for testing %ERRORLEVEL%.  I have seen this value be something other than 1 when a command fails.
2. setlocal enabledelayedexpansion handles the %ERRORLEVEL% variable changing after each execution of the for loop.  Without this, it would just evaluate to whatever was contained in the %ERRORLEVEL% variable when the for loop was entered.
3. goto :EOF at the end of your main script so your labels are not executed after the script completes.  Also add this at the end of your label to prevent the same (the exit I have in mine would prevent that as well, but you may not want to exit the script on failure).

Answer (score 0):

To handle `spaces` etc in usernames you can use this as your last command:

```
for /d %%x in ("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*") do del /q /s /f "%%x\*.sqlite"
```

This also assumes that the files you are deleting have a `.sqlite` extension.

The files will probably be locked if they are in use, if the browser hasn't been closed.